# file permissions set but unable to open it with emacs or edit strange in vi

Tags: vim, emacs

I have a directory that I want to share in a cluster so that another user can
use my program and do some changes to her needs.

I have root access and I just basically did

```
$sudo cp dir /home/visitors/usr1
```

When I checked the directory and their contents, I found that they belong to root, which was good so far, so I did

```
$chown *.* usr1
```

Now the directory and the files belong to usr1 and with the same permissions that I had originally, namely

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 usr1 users
```

(also the group is the same as mine).
Now, when I try to edit a file as usr1 in emacs, the window stays empty and below I can see a message:

```
Creating directory: permission denied, /home/visitors/usr1/.emacs.d/
```

If I try to edit a file, but using vim, I can save changes, but a warning is raised:

```
E138: Can't write viminfo file /home/visitors/usr1/.viminfo!
```

Any idea how to override this type of behaviour and be able to edit normally in both vim and emacs?

Comment: Don't you mean `$chown user1 *.*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages do not say anything about not being able to read or write the file you are editing; your usr1 does not seem to have write permissions on /home/visitors/usr1.  Check with

```
$ ls -ld /home/visitors/usr1
```

Comment: you were right, by some reason, the usr1 file was set to belong to root but not to the usr1

Answer (score 0):

The files that cannot be written do not match `*.*`, they are `.*`

I think you need to change permission on those as well. Try `ls -la` and see what the owner and permissions are.

Comment: Oops -- looks like I didn't format correctly. Thanks for editing.

Comment: To expand: `*.*` only matches nonhidden files that have a period somewhere in them. Not only does this exclude hidden files (those starting with a period), but also files with no period anywhere in them (such files are not uncommon).